# Function to detect change in an ordered list

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I who like to find a solution in T-SQL that could find a a way to detect a change in a given list or records.

The physical table is like this:

```
| id |val |
|----|----|
| 1  | A  |
|----|----|
| 2  | A  |
|----|----|
| 3  | B  |
|----|----|
| 4  | B  |
|----|----|
| 5  | A  |
|----|----|
| 6  | A  |
|----|----|
```

`id` is a sequencial integer

`val` is an arbitrary value

I would like to add an calculated field that could somehow denote a change of `val`

Desired result:

```
| id |val | segment |
|----|----|---------|
| 1  | A  | 1       |
|----|----|---------|
| 2  | A  | 1       |
|----|----|---------|
| 3  | B  | 2       |
|----|----|---------|
| 4  | B  | 2       |
|----|----|---------|
| 5  | A  | 3       |
|----|----|---------|
| 6  | A  | 3       |
|----|----|---------|
```

What I'm trying to do is the possibility to group by "segments" like this:

```
| from_id | to_id | val |
|---------|-------|-----|
|     1   |    2  |  A  |
|     3   |    4  |  B  |
|     5   |    6  |  A  |
|---------|-------|-----|
```

Comment: You may have to use a cursor, i'm tyring to think of a set based solution because I hate cursors, but i can't think of one... EDIT: I mean, you arnt reallying doing a set based operating becuase the order of your data is important...

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Can I ask what your trying to do? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: kralco626: post edited with clarification of my goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming SQL Server 2005+

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (
id INT PRIMARY KEY,
val CHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @T
SELECT 1,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 2,'A' UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'B' UNION ALL SELECT 4,'B' UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'A' UNION ALL SELECT 6,'A'

;WITH cte1 AS(
SELECT 
      id,
      val, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY id) AS Grp
FROM @T
),
cte2 AS(
SELECT 
      id,
      val, 
      MIN(id) OVER (PARTITION BY Grp, val) AS GrpStart
FROM cte1
)
SELECT 
      id,
      val, 
      DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY GrpStart) AS segment 
FROM cte2
```

Or the updated requirement is a bit simpler

```
;WITH cte AS(
SELECT 
      id,
      val, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val ORDER BY id) AS Grp
FROM @T
)
SELECT 
      val, 
      MIN(id) AS from_id,
      MAX(id) AS to_id
FROM cte
GROUP BY Grp, val
ORDER BY from_id
```

Comment: @user - if this solution works, you should deff use this one rather than mine. nice solution Martin...

Answer (score 0):

This might have to be modified a bit to work. Also, i never use loops, do this might not be the most efficient way to do it.

```
Declare @counter int

Set @counter = 1

Declare @seg int

Set @seg = 1

Declare @cur varchar(50)

Set @ cur = select val from table where id = 1

While @counter <= select max id from table

Begin

    if(@cur == select val from table where id = @counter)
        update table set segment = @seg where id = @counter
    else
    {
        set @cur = select val from table where id = @counter
        set @ seg = @seg + 1
        update table set segment = @seg where id = @counter
    }
    Set @counter = @counter + 1

End
```

Well thats the general idea anyways...